# how to remove the header(firstline) in all files and in a directory. and the file names still remain same in unix

Tags: shell

Example: In my folder 
C:\users\inputfiles contains 
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt with headers.

Need to remove the header in each file and move the data into same file( File name should not change) by using shell script

Answer (score 1):

sed and tail will help you with this.

No output redirection is required if sed is used.

```
sed -i '1d' filename
```

If you're using tail then use a intermediate tmp file to have the contents stored and then move that content of tmp file to the original file name.

```
tail -n +2 "$FILE" > "$FILE.tmp" && mv "$FILE.tmp" "$FILE"
```

tail will work faster compared to sed.

Answer (score 0):

Run This Command For Each of your File.

```
tail -n +2 "$FILE" > "$FILE.tmp" && mv "$FILE.tmp" "$FILE"
```

It should work.

Comment: This won't work since redirection takes place before the tail command and tail will work on a empty file. so if tail needs to be used then intermediate file has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the number of lines of the headers are all the same: 2

Give a try to this, to remove the lines before the 3 for each files with `.txt` suffix in current directory:

```
sed -n -i '3,$ p' *.txt
```

`-i`: modify each file directly